# $X$ Poisson distribution, $Y$ geometric distribution - how to find $P(Y>X)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, convolution

Suppose that $X$ has **Poisson distribution** with parameter $\lambda$ and that $Y$ has **geometric distribution** with parameter $p$ and is independent of $X$.

What is the  **$P(Y>X)$** ? *(the final formula should not contain any infinite sum).*

$X$ and $Y$ represent two different distributions and it is not a standard case with a sum of two independent variables. I am confused here. Does the convolution apply to this case? What should be the steps to solve this problem?

Comment: Hint: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and integer valued, $$P(Y>X)=\sum_nP(X=n)P(Y\ge n+1).$$

Comment: ok, from this point on I substituted the probabilities and got the correct answer 
however I still don't fully get the logic behind your formula. how would you interpret it?

$P(X=n)= e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!} \\
P(Y=n+1)=(1-p)^{(n+1)-1} \\
\\
\\
P(Y>X)=\sum_nP(X=n)P(Y\ge n+1)=\\
e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!} * (1-p)^{(n+1)-1}=  e^{-\lambda} * \frac{(\lambda(1-p))^n}{n!} = e^{-\lambda}*e^{\lambda(1-p)}=e^{-\lambda p}$

Comment: Bayes formula + independence of X and Y.

Comment: sorry, I don't follow that. 
do you mean the Bayes Theorem? $P(A|B)= \frac{P(B|A) P(A)}{P(B)}$ There are no inequalities here. Could you expound on that please?

Comment: can anyone explain the logic behind the formula $P(Y>X)=\sum_nP(X=n)P(Y\ge n+1)$?

Comment: Bayes formula is an equality, never an inequality, here $$P(Y>X)=\sum_nP(Y>X,X=n)=\sum_nP(Y>n,X=n)=\sum_nP(Y>n)P(X=n).$$

Comment: I got the transition now.  Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the record, there is the full solution to this problem

$P(X=n)= e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!} \\ P(Y=n+1)=(1-p)^{(n+1)-1} \\$

$P(Y>X)=\sum_n P(Y>X,X=n)= \sum_n P(Y>n,X=n)= \sum_n P(Y>n)P(X=n) = \sum_n P(Y\ge n+1) P(X=n)=  \\ = \sum_n (1-p)^{(n+1)-1} * e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!} = \sum_n e^{-\lambda} * \frac{(\lambda(1-p))^n}{n!} = e^{-\lambda}*e^{\lambda(1-p)}=e^{-\lambda p}$

Comment: Don't you feel uncomfortable that your solution involves sums over $n$ becoming one term depending on an unspecified $n$, which itself seems to retransform into a full sum?

Comment: is this solution incorrect?

Comment: Trivially so, for the reason explained in my previous comment. But $P(Y>X)=e^{-\lambda p}$.

Comment: I removed the sums, do you agree with the equation now?

Comment: Even less so. Some sums were *missing*, not the opposite.

Comment: do you agree now?

Comment: Yes the new-new formulation makes sense.

Comment: @Michal why did you use $P(Y=n+1)=(1-p)^{(n+1)-1}$ instead of $P(Y=n+1)=p(1-p)^{(n+1)-1}$

Comment: @  user101388  because $P(Y \geq k)=(1-p)^{k-1} $