# Why $P\left(Y>X\right)=\sum\limits_n P\left(X=n\right) \cdot P\left(Y\geq n+1\right)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

Joint Distribution Chapter of P exam book—Discrete case. Problem 41.7 (p exam book by M. Finan)

**Part** of the question's solution was already posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1436577/229317).
Michal's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1437107/229317) was:
\begin{align}
P\left(X=n\right)&=\frac{e^{−\lambda}\lambda^n}{n!}
\\ P\left(Y\geq n+1\right)&= \left(1−p\right)^{\left(n+1\right)−1}
\\ P\left(Y>X\right) &= {\textstyle \sum_n P\left(X=n\right) \cdot P\left(Y\geq n+1\right)}
\\ &= e^{−\lambda}\dfrac{\lambda^n}{n!}\, \left(1−p\right)^{(n+1)−1} 
\\ &= e^{−\lambda}\dfrac{\left(\lambda\left(1−p\right)\right)^n}{n!}
\\ &= e^{−\lambda }\cdot e^{\lambda \left(1−p\right)}
\\ &= e^{−\lambda p}.
\end{align}

**However**, I do not understand how you go from $\,P\left(Y>X\right)\,$ to $\;\sum_n P\left(X=n\right) \cdot P\left(Y\geq n+1\right)$.

In particular, I do not understand the $\,P\left(Y\geq n+1\right)$ part. Because, in application, this eliminates the '$p$' part of the geometric distribution $\,p\left(1-p\right)^{n-1}\,$ s.t. the answer after calculation is  $\,e^{\lambda p}$.

Since I don't understand why the $p$ was eliminated, I got $\,{pe}^{\lambda p}$.

Thanks!

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

In general, conditioning on $X=n$ would yield

\begin{align}
P(Y\gt X)&=\sum_nP(Y\gt X\cap X=n)\\
&=\sum_nP(Y\gt n\mid X=n)P(X=n)\;.
\end{align}

This just splits the event $Y\gt X$ into disjoint cases according to the value of $X$ and then applies the definition of the conditional probability.

In the problem you're quoting, $X$ and $Y$ are assumed to be independent, so $P(Y\gt n\mid X=n)$ is just $P(Y\gt n)$, and we have

$$
P(Y\gt X)=\sum_nP(Y\gt n)P(X=n)\;.
$$

Now just use $P(Y\gt n)=P(Y\ge n+1)$, which is true since $Y$ takes only integer values.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help in understanding the problem! It makes more sense now.