# Mean distance between 2 Random Variables with resp. Poisson and Geometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, poisson-distribution

Let $X$ be a random variable geometrically distributed with parameter $p$ and let $Y$ be a random variable with Poisson distribution following parameter $p$. $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Calculate $E[X  |  Y]$.

Calculate $E[|X - Y|]$.

How does one approach these calculations?

Comment: The first question has an evident answer: if $X$ is independent from $Y$, the knowledge of $Y$ doesn't influence in any way the knowledge we have about $X$, in particular its mathematical expectation.

Comment: For the second question, have a look at: (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1436577)

Comment: You know there are two definitions of a geometric distribution according to The fact that the first value is 0 or is 1: which one is yours ?

Comment: Have you seen how the reference I gave gives a solution for your second question ?

Comment: I have changed your title with the objective that this question is found 
 by future queries. Do you agree with it ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes that is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one we know by definition that 
$$E[Y|X] = \sum_y yf_{Y|X}(y|X)$$
but we can write 
$$f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{f_{Y,X}(y,x)}{f_X(x)}$$
and by independence 
$$f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{f_{Y}(y)f_X(x)}{f_X(x)}$$
so we just have 
$$\sum_y yf_Y(y)=E(Y)$$

For the second you can do a couple of things. Personally, my plan of attack would be to find the density of $Z=Y-X$ by transform of random variable method (or discrete convolution formula), then find the distribution of $|Z|$ and take the expected value.

Edit: that second answer was a cop out.
Lets look at $Z=Y-X$, we know from the convolution formula
$$F_{X-Y}(z)= P(X-Y <z)$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F_y(z+x)p_X(x)dx$$
Okay so we can evaluate that integral and find the density by differentiating the result, or we can push the derivative into the integral and write 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p_Y(z+x)p_X(x)dx$$
Okay so you can evaluate that expression and get some density using the definition of poisson/geometric. Lets find the final transform we need by defining the resulting density to map to the random variable $K$

So we know how $K$ is distributed from the previous step. Lets find the transform of $O=|K|$
How do we find this? Well we know $$P(O<o)=P(|K|<o)=P(-o < K < o)= P(K < o)-P(-o < K)=P(K<o)-P(o>K)$$

Which we can compute using the CDF we found above.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't agree with your "treatment" of the second question: you propose continuous methods instead of discrete ones; I don't think it is of any use, especialy for a beginner.

Comment: yeah, replace integrals with sums, you are welcome to write your own answer!

Comment: Pardon me, I have some knowledge in probability, but your "solution" is not a solution, it's  handwaving : I defy the OP (and you) to turn your indications with integrals into a real solution.

Comment: Yeah, you should go for it! That would be awesome to see a detailed solution...I am just too lazy right now

Comment: If you need a hint, the convolution formula is the exact same as above except with positive support and sums instead of integrals...detailed here..https://math.la.asu.edu/~jtaylor/teaching/Fall2010/STP421/lectures/lecture20.pdf and for the absolute value, the formula I gave above is valid for both PMFs and PDFs because algebra on CDFs is equally valid for both